# Chef knife site download return ContentLengthMismatch errors

Tags: chef-infra, opcode, knife, cookbook

After I upgraded my chef client on mac to version 11.10.4, I couldn't use knife command to download cookbooks. I have latest knife version and latest xcode 5.1 for Mac. Does anyone know what seem to be the issue?

```
$ knife cookbook site list
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ContentLengthMismatch: Response body length 2219 does not match HTTP Content-Length header 659.

$ knife cookbook site download apt
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ContentLengthMismatch: Response body length 2830 does not match HTTP Content-Length header 439.
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug in the software and has already been reported at https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5100

Comment: UPDATED: upgraded to version 11.12.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a reported bug in the latest release of Chef Client https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5100. You can downgrade your Chef installation and the problem will go away.

---

As pointed out in the comments, this has been fixed in 11.12.0.

Comment: This bug was fixed in Chef client 11.12.0, so upgrading can also solve the issue.

Comment: Can anyone provide a direct link to a 11.12.0 Ubuntu .deb package, preferably which will install on 14.04-LTS?

Comment: @fooquency just use the omnibus installer

Comment: @sethvargo Thanks; I've just discovered that that downloads packages in the background, making upgrading easy and within the scope of apt-get, it seems. That had been my concern.